# Aplicar Fecha de Caducidad a una aplicación (Trial version)

Tags: java, android

En algunas aplicaciones de pago, te muestra un diálogo para que puedas comprar la versión completa de la app, y en otros es la prueba de los 30 días.

¿Cómo aplicar una fecha de caducidad a una aplicación en Android?

Comment: Interesante lo que preguntas, algunas apps no ser como lo hacen porque si las borras y las vuelves a instalar, no cuentan de 0 sino ya de los días transcurridos, como lo hace solid explorer

Comment: Entiendo que la mejor manera sería crear un usuario enlacado a Google Play o uno local y  poner una fecha de registro. Cada vez que se conecta mirar esta fecha y ya.

Comment: Lo que hacen es coger el `imei` del telefono para saber si lo has instalado previamente porque lo guardaran es sus bases de datos @Webserveis

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Respuesta inspirada en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995719/creating-an-android-trial-application-that-expires-after-a-fixed-time-period), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223552/how-to-time-bomb-an-android-application), [mobile-trial](https://github.com/mobile-trial)

Maneras que se podría implementar, de más simple de saltarse a más complejo.

- **Primer método** guardar la fecha de instalación en `base de datos`, `fichero interno o externo de la app` o usar `shared preferences`.
  Pero es muy probable que el usuario se salte la restricción del tiempo de prueba:, *desinstalado y instalado de nuevo la app*, si se usa una ubicación externa para el archivo, puede que el usuario no se de cuenta del residuo.
- **Segundo método:** usar una fecha limite fija `hard bomb-time` es decir que para todos los usuarios a tal fecha expira. Es fácil de saltarse esa restricción, solo *cambiar la hora del sistema por una fecha anterior a la fecha limite*, para el usuario le puede ser un poco engorroso hacerlo a menudo y decide comprar.
- **Tercer método** de todos lo otro es el más seguro (pero no infalible) eso si requiere de más recursos, conexión a `internet`, `servidor web propio`, es crear un comprobador remoto de identificador único, se puede obtener `getDeviceId` del dispositivo y comprobar a la base de datos remota si existe, obtenga la fecha de instalación, si no existe que agregue un nuevo entrada `getDeviceId : fecha agregación`.
  si el dispositivo no tiene internet se puede advertir al usuario y finalizar la app.

#### Código de cada método

no comprobado si funcionan:

**Ejemplo del primer método** usando `SharedPreference`

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String installDate = preferences.getString("InstallDate", null);
    if(installDate == null) {
        // First run, so save the current date
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateString = formatter.format(now);
        editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        // This is not the 1st run, check install date
        Date before = (Date)formatter.parse(installDate);
        Date now = new Date();
        long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - before.getTimeInMillis();
        long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
        if(days > 30) { // More than 30 days?
             // Expired !!!
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**Ejemplo del segundo método** usando `time-bomb`

```
protected void onResume()
{   
    super.onResume();

    Calendar expirationDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    expirationDate.set(2016, 12, 31);  //expirara final de año
    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();  //obtener fecha actual
    if (t.compareTo(expirationDate) == 1)
       finish();
}
```

**Ejemplo del tercer método** respuesta del usuario @Martin_christmman implementar https://github.com/mobile-trial

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda, me ha ayudado demasiado

Comment: Existe alguna forma de hacerlo para una aplicación que funciona totalmente offline (en la que el pago no se realiza a través de internet)?

Comment: @AdrianaHernández se me acude hacerlo mediante la instalación de una versión key, que cuando pague el usuario se le envia el apk, y la apk trial version si detecta el paquete de la key está instalado active toda la funcionalidad.

Comment: Eso es una buena idea para que el usuario, al pagar la versión completa, se le activen nuevas funcionalidades, pero en este caso siempre tendrá activa todas las funcionalidades que tuvo desde el inicio en la version trial. Ahora, en mi caso lo que necesito es, pasado un tiempo, o en una fecha determinada ciertas funcionalidades, que antes estaban activas, ahora queden inactivas en todos los dispositivos que este instalada la apk, hasta que el usuario actualice a la siguiente versión

Comment: @AdrianaHernández pues yo implementaria el segundo método, es decir a 30 dias se desactivan, hasta la espera de la nueva actualización, o bien el primero , el tercer metodo es el que requiere internet

Comment: Si, entiendo que se puede hacer así, pero lo que quisiera saber es si existe algo mas seguro (como el tercer método), pero offline, en donde el usuario de la app no lo resuelva simplemente cambiándole la fecha al dispositivo. @Webserveis