# Como aplicar Fecha de Caducidad (Trial version) a una aplicación android que funciona de forma offline

Tags: java, android

Primero aclarar que esta pregunta no es un duplicado de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22207/aplicar-fecha-de-caducidad-a-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-trial-version).

Necesito saber como puedo hacer lo que se plantea en [esta misma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22207/aplicar-fecha-de-caducidad-a-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-trial-version) pregunta, pero para una aplicación android de pago que funciona totalmente offline, en la que el pago no se realiza a través de internet.

O sea, lo que necesito es que, pasado un tiempo, o en una fecha determinada, ciertas funcionalidades que antes estaban activas, ahora queden inactivas en todos los dispositivos que este instalada la apk, hasta que el usuario actualice a la siguiente versión. Todo esto de forma offline, ya que me encuentro en un país del tercer mundo en el que no existen estas comodidades de hacerlo con internet.

Ah! y un detalle mas, necesito hacerlo de una forma segura. En la que el usuario no pueda hacer algo como simplemente cambiarle la fecha al dispositivo y volver a tener las funcionalidades activas.

En la pregunta antes mencionada se da una solución pero es con internet, necesito una idea de como hacer esto desde la propia aplicación de forma offline y **segura**. (Por esto ultimo es que el primer y segundo método planteado en la respuesta no satisfacen mi duda).

Comment: Cual es la diferencia de tu pregunta con la que enlazas?

Comment: La diferencia es que yo necesito una solución sin conexión a internet, desde la propia aplicación.

Comment: acabo de ver la actualización de tu pregunta, de los 3 métodos que te han respondido, 2 son offline.

Comment: Si pero no son métodos seguros, en ellos el usuario puede hacer algo como cambiarle la fecha al dispositivo y ya vuelven a tener la app con todo. Perdona, volví a actualizar la pregunta, aclarando esto. @fredyfx

Comment: Se me ocurre una variación del primer método, pero digamos eticamente rasca limites de malware/virus. consulta campo esteneografía

Comment: Si no es por internet, ¿cómo se distribuye la aplicación? ¿tenés acceso a los dispositivos luego de ser instalados como para ingresarles una llave de autorización?

Comment: tengo en mente un algoritmo, espero sirva de alguna manera :D

Comment: Si es offline posiblemente cualquier idea que desarrolles tenga sus vulnerabilidades.

Comment: Coincido con Mariano, ¿podrías explicar cómo vas a distribuir la aplicación?

Comment: Respondiendo la pregunta de @Mariano... En mi país hay varias vías para distribuir la app, y ninguna de ellas es internet desgraciadamente. Y no, no tengo acceso a los dispositivos luego de ser instalada. Se que puede que en todos los casos que existan habrá vulnerabilidades haciendolo desde la propia app de forma offline, pero es la unica opcion que tengo y quizas alguien tenga una buena idea para hacer esto aunque no sea la mas óptima

Answer (score 4):

Casos para el bypass de la clásica validación de los trials:

1. Que coloquen una fecha antes de la fecha de instalación.
2. Que coloquen unos días antes de la fecha de expiración.
3. Que reinstalen la aplicación.

Te comparto el algoritmo que tengo en el C:\erebro en este momento:

Necesitarás obtener la fecha actual y generar el resto de días válidos para el uso de tu app guardando dicha información en una tabla (`SQLite` recomendado).

También un contador que inicie en 0 junto con todas las fechas generadas y vaya sumando día a día válido: conociendo qué dia fue ayer y qué día fue antes de ayer, si la diferencia de ayer con el día de hoy es 1 quiere decir que la fecha no ha sido alterada, caso contrario, bloquear la app hasta que el usuario coloque la fecha correcta: sumale +1 a la fecha de ayer y ya!

Validar que tu app esté funcionando en el rango definido: desde la fecha de instalación hasta el plazo determinado: 30 días por ejemplo.

Qué pasa si le cambian la fecha a días antes de la instalación? No funciona porque está fuera del rango.

Qué sucede si le cambian la fecha a un día antes de la finalización del trial? El contador validará, ergo app bloqueada.

Qué hago si el usuario reinstala la app? Aquí se pone muy interesante, pues hay que echarle un ojo a la activacion de la app: Existen soluciones como `Twilio.com`, `Plivo.com`, `Bandwidth.com` que permiten el envío de SMS desde tu aplicación web, puedes configurar para que envíe algún código en especial y en tu app móvil se active mediante eso, para ello te recomiendo gestionar a tus usuarios.

Comment: El master ayudando a los nuevos, ando sin internet, pero pronto volvere

Comment: Está muy interesante tu solución, pensaré más en esto y lo probaré, ya que quizá sea lo que mas se acerca a lo que quiero lograr. Si me funciona como quiero te lo haré saber. Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Muchas de nadas :D que la fuerza os acompañe! Éxitos y bendiciones en el proyecto :D

Comment: Pero no se borran los datos de sqlite, si el usuario va ajustes de la app y da borrar todo?

Comment: @Webserveis pensando de otro modo, si el usuario borra todo desde ajustes, tendría que volver a validar la app, tiene mucha similitud con "Qué hago si el usuario reinstala la app?"

Answer (score 2):

Veo que entiendes que sin un tercero (un server) no existe aproximación infalible, por lo que buscas una solución que complique la vida lo mas posible al usuario que quiera intentar hacer un *reset* del trial.

Sugiero los siguientes puntos.

1. Guarda la fecha de instalación usando [Backup SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html). Esto te permite disponer de la información incluso aunque la persona re instale la aplicación.
2. Cada vez que la persona se vaya de la aplicación, guarda el tiempo usando las funciones `elapsedRealtime()` o `elapsedRealtimeNanos()`. Estas son funciones monótonas ascendientes, que indican el tiempo desde el último *boot*. Una función monótona ascendiente significa que **el tiempo siempre crece**, **sin importar si el usuario ha modificado la hora del sistema**. Este método **no** te permitirá contar desde la fecha de instalación, pero si acumulas suficientes lecturas y compruebas que su suma es **mayor al tiempo de tu *trial***, entonces es un estado inválido (el usuario está intentando modificar las fechas) y sabrás que el trial ha caducado.

Dado que no siempre podrás acumular esta lectura, es posible que el usuario cambie la fecha y prolongue un poco el *trial*, pero podrás darte cuenta después de un tiempo no muy grande.

3. Adicionalmente puedes incluir en tu app ser notificada **cuando el usuario cambia la hora (o se mueve de zona horaria etc)**. Tienes lo siguientes Intent Filters disponibles:

ACTION_TIME_TICK
ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Este método por si solo no es suficiente, pues el usuario podría desinstalar la app, cambiar la hora y volver a instalarla, por lo que no recibirías los *callbacks*

Finalmente podrías usar un `AlarmManager`, de tal manera que recibirás un mensaje en la fecha en que acabe el trial, y podrás persistir la información para ser inmune a los cambios de fechas.

Answer (score 0):

### Es matemáticamente imposible hacerlo de forma segura...

en un dispositivo que no se encuentra bajo tu control.

Por ejemplo :

- Crea un dispositivo virtual con cualquier emulador de Android.
- Instala el programa.
- Haz una copia de seguridad de los archivos de la máquina virtual que has creado.
- Ya tienes una copia perfecta a la que volver cuando se acabe el tiempo de prueba.

En un dispositivo físico tambien puedes hacer copias binarias y restaurar.

Con una técnica así de sencilla es posible vencer cualquier protección offline basada en expiración de tiempo de prueba. Aunque es un poco incómodo tener que empezar de cero cada mes (o periodo de prueba). Hay ataques más sofisticados, como la ingeniería inversa.

Comment: Si te entiendo, y se que posiblemente no exista una forma 100% segura, pero esa es la idea, que el usuario común tenga que pasar un poco mas de trabajo (y con algo de conocimiento requerido) para romper la seguridad

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que se me ocurre a mi es que, cuando una persona vaya a usar tu aplicación lo hagas de la siguiente forma:

1. Permites instalar la aplicación
2. Deberías al menos conectarse a internet que para activarla, sea versión gratuita o de pago
3. Con un código que tu des, posiblemente enviando por correo, lo ponen en la aplicación
4. Y de esa forma te libras de cualquier cosa

Debes tener una base de datos en un servidor con un servicio el cual ayude a verificar que códigos, son para versión de pago, cual para versión gratuita y cuales están en uso y cual ya usaron.

Comment: El problema es que lo que necesito es que pasado el tiempo definido queden inactivas algunas de las funcionalidades de la app de la versión trial (por llamarle de alguna manera a la primera versión), hasta que se actualice a la próxima versión. Y este tiempo se le aplicará a todos los dispositivos que la tengan instalada

Comment: El problema es que, tendria qu existir alguna forma de que puedas instalar alguna carpeta que guarde una especie de cache que si la aplicacion ya fue instalada una vez por mas que la instales siga en trial version